# Find Corresponding Value Based on Today's Date Falling Between Week-Ending Dates in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, index-match

I have an Excel table that ranges from cells B2 to T11. The first row in this range (B2:T2) contains dates, which are essentially week-ending dates representing Fridays of each week. I need to create an Excel formula to find out which week-ending date encompasses today's date and return the corresponding value from B3:T3.

The dates in B2:T2 are not necessarily matching today's date exactly, but I want to check if today's date falls within the range from the previous week-ending date to the current week-ending date. Once I find that range, I'd like to pull the corresponding value from row 3 (B3:T3):

### This has been my attempt:

```
=INDEX($B3:$T3, 1, SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$T$2 >=TODAY() - WEEKDAY(TODAY(), 3)), --($B$2:$T$2 <= TODAY() + (6 - WEEKDAY(TODAY(), 3)))))
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Is this a table structure, or regular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you can use

`=XLOOKUP(TODAY(),B2:T2,B3:T3,"-",1,1)`

The second last 1 tells Excel to look for an exact or greater date.

Answer (score 1):

Try this the dates must be in ascending order in row 2.

```
=HLOOKUP(TODAY(),B2:T3,2,TRUE)
```

Comment: I had tried this but i get a #N/A

Comment: @nicol if the dates are in text format, or all of the dates are later than today you get #N/A